# Unable to add newline / carriage return in yahoo mail

Tags: html, anchor, html-email, yahoo-mail

I am accessing yahoo compose from my application. The following is my sample code.

```
<a href="http://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?to=m@m.com&amp;subj=Sample&body=Line1%0D%0ALine2&cc=" target="_blank"> Yahoo Mail</a>
```

The following is my output

[image]

But I need to add a new line between line1 and Line2.

My expected output is

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this can be done in 2 different ways:

1. add `<br />` between line 1 and 2
2. Use `<table>`. Put line 1 and line 2 in separate `<tr>`.

Comment: No use the both not working. Do you have any other idea? <a href="http://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?to=m@m.com&amp;subj=Sample&body=<table><tr><td>Line1Line2<td></tr><tr><td>Line1Line2<td></tr></table>&cc=" target="_blank"> Yahoo Mail</a>